# A little JS help here please.. avoiding errors with undefined objects/variables (suppression perhaps?)

Tags: javascript, variables, object, undefined

I'm slightly annoyed at JS stopping at a simple UNDEFINED error..

I have a routine where i need to "set" variables based on what's already in the global scope

```
targetID = myData.id;
targetID = myData.targetValue;
```

these objects may or may not be set, depending on previous operations...

i often get this error:

```
TypeError: myData is undefined
targetValue =  myData.targetValue;
```

and the rest of the JS code stops executing!

annoying..

coming from PHP and AS2 and other languages, the script never stops on me just coz of an undefined value..

now i know i can simply test for "undefined" before setting the variable.. but in reality I have a whole bunch of variables to set and running a condition on "each" is a bit stupid..

How do i tell JS to just continue running regardless of undefined vars/objects?

or atleast, how do i suppress errors specific to a code (NOT GLOBAL) ..

in php, preceding a call w/ "@" symbol suppresses any warnings or error..

Comment: Why does your code not know whether the variables are set or not?

Comment: it's dynamic.. it's hard to explain. but basically, im developing my own CRUD engine.. so you can expect the unexpected variables and objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not that the value is `undefined`. The problem is that you're trying to access a property on `undefined`, which throws an error (which it should do).

I don't know PHP, but I can't imagine it doesn't throw an error when something like this happens.

What you could do to prevent this is the following:

```
myData = myData || {};  // this will assure that myData is not undefined. That way the next call will not try to retrieve a property on undefined.
targetID = myData.id;
targetID = myData.targetValue;
```

Comment: ohhhh. i get it.. you're right! and this is an elegant solution .. thanks very very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use a guard operator. Check if the object exists before trying to read its property.

```
targetID = myData && myData.id || "default value";
```

So what happens there is if `myData` exists, then use `myData.id`, else, use this `"default value"`

If you want to do this for a group of variables, you can do:

```
var targetId, targetValue;
if( myData ) {
    targetId = myData.id;
    targetValue = myData.value;
}
```

Comment: i'd hate to have to do this to each of the vars i want to set.. but thank you.. this technique will come in handy.

Comment: You don't have to check for every one, just for the ones that might be undefined. If have a group of vars, just initialize them at first, and only do the assignment if the object exists. I updated my answer.